# Unable to bind handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, components

I am trying to bind a method of a parent component to the state of its child component but I'm unable to get the desired result. I checked the value of 'this' in App component and it still points to the App component. Should it not be pointing to the ItemsList component since its being binded to it using bind()? Can someone please point out the mistake I'm making.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div> {this.props.value} </div>;
  }
}

class ItemList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemArray: ['Work', 'Learn React']
    }
    this.props.adder.bind(this);
    console.log(this.props.adder)
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.state.itemArray.map(el=><Item key={el} value={el} />);
    return (
      <div> 
        <h2> To Do List </h2>
        <ul>{items}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  addElement (data) {
    let items = this.state.ItemList;
    items.push(<Item value={data} />);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={input=>this.input=input} />
        <input type="button" value="Add" onClick={()=>this.addElement(this.input.value)}/>
        <ItemList adder={this.addElement} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should it not be pointing to the ItemsList component since its being binded to it using bind()?

Well,the step you following in not right one.

**In `App` Component**

You need to store the `ItemList` (child) component reference in  App(`parent`) component.

```
<ItemList adder={this.addElement} bindChild =  {(ref)=>this.itemList = ref}/>
```

**In `ItemList` component**,

you need to call `bindChild` method when `ItemList` component mounted.

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.bindChild(this);
}
```

Now, in your `App` (parent) component, you have reference for **`ItemList`** (child) component in `this.itemList` property.

In `App` component, you can use `this.itemList` to update state of `ItemList` (child) component.

```
addElement(data) {
    let items = this.itemList.state.itemArray;
    console.log(items);
    const newItem = <Item value={data} />

    this.itemList.setState({ itemArray : [...items, newItem]})
  }
```

Please check complete example on [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvj51o5x4l)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Just one more thing I wanted to ask. Where should we ideally place 'this.props.bindChild(this)' . In 'constructor' or 'componentDidMount' and why ?

Comment: You need `this` object.So,you can call it in . constructor as well

Answer (score 1):

Though what you want is technically possible, this is a much more explicit easy to understand way to do it.

I re-factored your code so that the data flow only goes in one direction, from `App` to `Itemimport React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

I also changed `Item` and `ItemList` to stateless components that take `value` and `items` as props respectively.

The main change is that `App` holds the state instead of `ItemList`

```
const Item = ({ value }) => <div>{value}</div>;

const ItemList = ({ items }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>To Do List</h2>
    {items.map(item => <Item key={item} value={item} />)}
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: ["Work", "Learn React"]
    };
  }
  addElement(value) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: [...state.items, value]
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={input => (this.input = input)} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Add"
          onClick={() => this.addElement(this.input.value)}
        />
        <ItemList items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Here is a CodeSandbox with your working app: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r4v0w5o94

Comment: Yeah . But I guess this will not work either as we can't mutate props and either way there is no way to propagate this binded function upward to the parent. Is there any other way I can achieve binding callback of the parent inside a child ?

Comment: I have re-factored your code and edited my answer. Let me know if you have any questions